# Cannot create store view

Tags: magento-2.1.2, system.log

I'm trying to **create a store view** and i'm getting an error.

In the browser it says: `One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running`.

I tried to run the `reindex` command, cron run commands and nothing has worked.

Looking at my `debug.log` and `system.log` I see this:

**debug.log**

```
`[2016-11-17 09:24:16] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://my.ip.address/admin/admin/system_store/save/key/082334a1ecfb2f5f13159ea2677dc79e89b45967ff0d0086304df69113b44a91/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":[],"mode":"all"},"is_exception":false} []`
```

**system.log**

```
`[2016-11-17 09:24:16] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Warning: is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 512
Trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'is_file() expec...', '/var/www/html/v...', 512, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(512): is_file('/var/www/html/v...')`
```

....and a long trace with different paths

Seems to me like the no reindexing or cron changing will fix this, since the problem is in the software itself.

Comment: Delete var folder and run again re indexing command.

Answer (score 4):

May be problem with caching issue, check it with my below suggestion.

1. Remove **/var/cache** folder from root path.

Run below command for re-indexing.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Just need to remove `/var/cache`. Don't remove your entire `var` folder

Comment: Not functionally, but you will lose old logs, product imports and exports and reports which you may want to keep

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer. You can check it.

Answer (score 1):

Ssh to your root magento installation, then reindex data with bellow command:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Then remove the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And finally give access to your apache user:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data ./*
```

I believe this will solve problems of that type.